# Wordpress Install Shows Index Of /

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am trying to move my custom wordpress theme from my localhost on my machine to a server. I have done this countless times, but it has never been my server, and this is a first for me doing it on my own server. I have exported the SQL file from my local phpMyAdmin, created a new database on the server, added user with all permissions, added user to database, edited wp-config to match the newly created info, have an index.php in the root of the wordpress install and have an htaccess file, both of which are from wordpress itself and are un-edited and have imported the SQL file from the local install.

After uploading the files via FTP, the site shows Index Of /(sitename) 
When clicking on index.php manually, it brings me to the site (after having to add an ID line in the register_sidebar function in functions.php) but still does not show up properly and does not work on other devices.

After playing with some configuration and un-installing and re-installing MAMP, a test wordpress install gives me an error of

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

when attempting to import the SQL file into the newly created database on the remote server. This test install also gives me an error of "Cannot connect to server" when manually clicking on index.php

Am I missing something here that I am supposed to be doing? Or is there some kind of server configuration that needs to be done in order to support a wordpress install? Any and all help is much appreciated as this has been driving me crazy for almost a week.

Comment: I use the plugin called "Duplicator", it makes the transfer much easier and faster. It's a good alternative since it has a very low failure rate!

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems with that user permissions. Have you tried connecting manually with that database user and trying to create objects on that exact database?